# Flexbox wrapping without specific height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have an html structure that I would like to display in different ways for smaller and bigger screens, like so:

***Bigger screens***

```
 -----------    ------------------------------      -----------
|           |  |           Section A          |    |           |
|           |   ------------------------------     |           |
| Section B |  |           Section D          |    | Section C |
|           |   ------------------------------     |           |
|           |  |           Section E          |    |           |
 -----------    ------------------------------      -----------
```

***Smaller screens***

```
 ------------------------------ 
|           Section A          |
 ------------------------------ 
|           Section B          |
 ------------------------------  
|           Section C          | 
 ------------------------------  
|           Section D          | 
 ------------------------------  
|           Section E          | 
 ------------------------------
```

## What I currently have

I managed to get something very similar:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.section {
  background: gray;
  flex: 1; order: 1;
}
.pull {
  background: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .section {
    order: 2;
    width: 80%;
    flex: 1 0 25%;
  }
  
  .pull {
    width: 10%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  .left {
    order:1;
  }
  .right {
    order:3;
  }
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="section">Section A</div>
  <div class="section pull left">Section B</div>
  <div class="section pull right">Section C</div>
  <div class="section">Section D</div>
  <div class="section">Section E</div>
</div>
```

## And the problem is..

I need to get this layout working *regardless* of height in *either* sections. See a demonstration of the issue:

```css
.bigtext { height: 500px; background: red }
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.section {
  background: gray;
  flex: 1; order: 1;
}
.pull {
  background: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .section {
    order: 2;
    width: 80%;
    flex: 1 0 25%;
  }
  
  .pull {
    width: 10%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  .left {
    order:1;
  }
  .right {
    order:3;
  }
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="section">Section A</div>
  <div class="section pull left">Section B</div>
  <div class="section pull right">Section C</div>
  <div class="section"><div class="bigtext">hi</div></div>
  <div class="section">Section E</div>
</div>
```

On smaller screens, sections should always be stacked on top of each other.

On bigger screens, each section should take the height of its descendants, without harming the structure. That is true for the side columns (sections B and C) that should always stick to the sides, as well as the middle sections (A, D, E) that should alway appear in that order on top of each other.

**I should note that scrolling on the page should be possible, if the height of sections (in total) is bigger than viewport, as one would expect in a regular web page.**

I did not manage to do that. I hope anyone here can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky question here. I have not been able to get a purely CSS solution to this either, as it seems you will need some wrappers somewhere to group things as you'd like no matter what.

However, with a little JavaScript added, we can accomplish what we want. Hopefully that's an option for you.

In the snippet below, I've grouped the markup into three columns based on the desktop layout, and then use JS to remove the wrappers on smaller screens, so that the inner sections may be reordered with the `order` property.

A fuller example would involve wrapping and unwrapping the sections on resize. That much isn't included below.

```js
$(function() {
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 999px)').matches) {
    $('.section').unwrap();
  }
})
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#col1, #col3 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
#col2 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.section.B, .section.C {
  height: 100%;
}
p, h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .section.A {
    order: 1
  }
  .section.B {
    order: 2;
  }
  .section.C {
    order: 3;
  }
  .section.D {
    order: 4;
  }
  .section.E {
    order: 5;
  }
}
.section.A { background: red; }
.section.B { background: blue; }
.section.C { background: yellow; }
.section.D { background: green; }
.section.E { background: grey; }
.section.F { background: lightblue; }
.section.G { background: gold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="col1">
  <div class="section B">
    <h3>Section B</h3>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="col2">
  <div class="section A">
    <h3>Section A</h3>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section D">
    <h3>Section D</h3>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section E">
    <h3>Section E</h3>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="col3">
  <div class="section C">
    <h3>Section C</h3>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm hoping there's a way to achieve that without changing the DOM. That's the last resort for me. Thanks for the try though!